# JavaScript resources for a static table

Tags: javascript

I want to display a static table on a webpage with the standard 'bells-n-whistles' like hover-color,etc. Does anyone have a good resource to recommend?

Comment: Don't use any javascript for it.

Comment: For hover-color, check out CSS.

Comment: Javascript would be way overkill for this project.  You just need HTML and CSS

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I agree with the other answers presesnted here. You set up the table with html and use this attribute `:hover` to make changes you want to apply. If you need resources on styles or just give you ideas. HTML5Rocks and CSS-Tricks are great resources for that.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/

https://css-tricks.com/